# How can I programmatically import a .bacpac file into an on-premises SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, docker-compose, azure-sql-database, bacpac

I am working on a project which hosts multiple services in Microsoft Azure, including their own databases, which are Azure SQL Databases. The development happens on developer laptops using Docker Compose including the database server which is using the `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest` docker image.

The task at hand is to create a scripted solution with PowerShell, which can import backups into both Azure SQL Database and the SQL Server running in Docker manually. This way, we want to export and version different sets of testdata, which we want to import into Azure environments after a deployment in some cases or use it to create a data baseline for local development.

Even though both databases are Microsoft SQL Servers, [they are different products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkEZm.png) built from the same codebase for different environments and different supported feature sets. (Screenshot taken in the Azure Portal)

The Azure SQL Database does not work with `*.bak` files, that leaves the `*.bacpac` format, which is the recommended solution for manual exports in Azure SQL Database (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export?view=azuresql)). The import into another Azure SQL Database is quite simple, using the [New-AzSqlDatabaseImport Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/new-azsqldatabaseimport?view=azps-9.1.0).
What I have been unable to find so far is a way to programmatically import the `*.bacpac` into my SQL Server in Docker as part of the PowerShell script.

Not all developers use Windows machines, so a solution that is cross-platform or inside the Docker container is required.

I have tried:

- using the T-SQL command [RESTORE DATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), which didn't work, because it expects a `*.bak` file
- using the `sqlpackage` utility as described in step 6 of [this article](https://reverentgeek.com/sql-server-for-linux-how-to-move-a-database-from-one-docker-container-to-another/), but that utility was not found in the container (`starting container process caused: exec: "/opt/mssql/bin/sqlpackage": stat /opt/mssql/bin/sqlpackage: no such file or directory: unknown`)

The only way I have found so far to import the `*.bacpac` file so far is manually by using the SSMS *Import Data-tier Application* wizard, but not in any way I can use in a PowerShell script.

I really *really* want to stay with a backup file solution and avoid exporting my databases to T-SQL scripts. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "but that utility was not found in the container" - sure. But you can create a container that *does* have it. I did a web search for "sqlpackage docker" and found both ready-made containers and docker file specs that you should be able to use to create your own container that has what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The comment above is correct - you can accomplish this by adding sqlpackage to your Docker container.

I have a [Github project to convert .bak to .bacpac](https://github.com/grrlgeek/bak-to-bacpac), and I built a [Docker container with SQL Server and sqlpackage](https://github.com/grrlgeek/bak-to-bacpac/blob/main/container/Docker/Dockerfile).